# How to check the number of fixed time segments between two dates?

Tags: java, android, date, time, jodatime

Two Dates are given:

Let's say,

> Date dt1 = 22 June 2013 8:00 PM
>
> Date dt2 = 24 June 2013 6:00 AM

Given the two dates, I want to determine that how many segments from **1 am to 5 am** are between these two dates.

For above, there are two segments:

> 23 June 1 am to 5am
>
> 24 June 1am to 5am

So the answer should be 2.

I can get the difference between the two times,

```
var time1 = new Date(dt1).getTime();
  var time2 = new Date(dt2).getTime();

  var diff = new Date(time1 - time2);
```

And the number of hours, min and seconds,

```
  var hours = diff.getHours();
  var minutes = diff.getMinutes();
  var seconds = diff.getMinutes();
```

But this only gives difference as expected.

What approach is needed to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Like everything else in computer science: break the problem down into a series of smaller problems that you're able to solve.

For example, in this problem you might simply determine if there's at least one of your "segments" in the time span. If there is, you might remove the first 24 hours from the full time span, then repeat the process for as long as there exists 24 hours to remove. Remember to count along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to check

- if `time1.getHours()` before or equal to 1am then `result=1`
- if `time2.getHours()` after 5am then `resutl++`
- `result+= diff.getDays() - 1`

Comment: result is coming as 1.  But it should be 2. `diff.getDays()` is returning 1. Getting it using `int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();`. And the result = 1 + (1-1) = 1.So why we are subtracting 1 from diff.getDays() ?